# How can I make UIImageView change its image programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
landscape.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tenerife1.png"];
}
```

First, I created an `UIImageView` with `IBOutlet`. Landscape is pointing to that `UIImageView`. In `InterfaceBuilder` I told to show an specific image in that `UIImageView`. It never changes. I always see the image I specified in `InterfaceBuilder`. But I want to set it programmatically. How can I do this?

Comment: Make sure the outlet is connected in IB

Comment: see this-----

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321374/cocoa-touch-adding-a-uiimageview-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible you did not have a custom view set up for that nib file? I had the same problem. I created a UIview subclass for that view controller, went into Interface Builder and set the view to that UIView subclass and then added an import header for the UIView into the Controller class. thats what did it for me

Answer (score 4):

Try calling setNeedsDisplay on the view after you change the image:

```
   [landscape setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to call setNeedsDisplay

Comment: I didn't think so either, but I was looking at some code that I had that was doing the exact same thing, and I was calling setNeedsDisplay - probably unnecessary, but was just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code, it might help you:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
landscape.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tenerife1.png"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about connection between imageview and File's Owner in InterfaceBuilder.

it's only you need after that:

```
landscape.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tenerife1.png"];
```