# Cocoa Touch - Adding a UIImageView programmatically?

Tags: cocoa-touch

How can I create and position a new imageview in objective-c?

Thanks!

I tried this but it doesnt seem to do anything...

```
-(void)drawStars{ //uses random numbers to display a star on screen
    //create random position
    int xCoordinate = arc4random() % 10;
    int yCoordinate = arc4random() % 10;

    UIImageView *starImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 58, 40)]; //create ImageView 

    starImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];


    [starImgView release];
```

I placed this method in my viewcontroller. I see some CG stuff do I need to import core graphics or something? (what is core graphics anyway?)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are asking about iPhone image view. Right? Then try this

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
```

This will create an image view of 100 x 50 dimension and locating (10, 10) of parent view.

Check the reference manual for [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). You can set an image by using [image](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image) property of imageView.

```
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a_image.png"];
```

And you can use the [contentMode](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode) property of UIView to configure how to fit the image in the view. For example you can use

```
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter
```

to place the desired image to the center of the view. The available contentModes are listed [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode)

Comment: how do you define the image to be shown?

Yes, Cocoa touch is iPhone only.

Comment: Also whats the limit for the position..Like whats the maximun before it goes off screen?

Answer (score 22):

You haven't added your view as a subview to another view, meaning it isn't in the view hierarchy.

Assuming you are doing this in a view controller, it might look something like:

```
[self.view addSubview: imgView];
```

Comment: @Darryl, that adds the image horizontally in the view controller, what if I want to have then lay out vertically?

Answer (score 1):

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.layer.frame.size.width, self.view.layer.frame.size.height)];
   imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emptyCart.jpeg"];
   imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
   [self.view addSubview: imgView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with passing the value `NSSArray` to `NSString`,

I got the answer:

```
//Display all images....
    NSString *imgstring= [self.allimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.myimages.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imgstring];     //displaying Images in UIImageView..noproblem.

// Display all numbers...
    cell.mylables.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [mysetobjectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];  //showing results fine ArghyA..
```